GDB shows source file names for global variables and functions
I'm using gdb to attach to a running process on a Linux system. As you can see info files shows the sections from the ELF executable mapped into process's virtual memory as well as the sections from the loaded shared .so libraries.
root@host:/# gdb -q attach 7173
attach: No such file or directory.
Attaching to process 7173
[New LWP 17381]
[New LWP 17380]
[New LWP 17379]

warning: Expected absolute pathname for libpthread in the inferior, but got target:/lib64/libpthread.so.0.

warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
0x00007f0bf997ac73 in epoll_wait () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81

warning: 81     ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory
(gdb) info files
Symbols from "target:/proc/7173/exe".
Native process:
        Using the running image of attached process 7173.
        While running this, GDB does not access memory from...
Local exec file:
        `target:/proc/7173/exe', file type elf64-x86-64.
        Entry point: 0x564521600970
        0x00005645215fa200 - 0x00005645215fa21c is .interp
        0x00005645215fa21c - 0x00005645215fa23c is .note.ABI-tag
        0x00005645215fa23c - 0x00005645215fa260 is .note.gnu.build-id
        0x00005645215fa260 - 0x00005645215fb0b8 is .dynsym
        0x00005645215fb0b8 - 0x00005645215fb1ea is .gnu.version
        0x00005645215fb1ec - 0x00005645215fb23c is .gnu.version_r
        0x00005645215fb240 - 0x00005645215fb588 is .gnu.hash
        0x00005645215fb588 - 0x00005645215fcc2c is .dynstr
        0x00005645215fcc30 - 0x00005645215fe850 is .rela.dyn
        0x00005645215fe850 - 0x00005645215feaf0 is .rela.plt
        0x00005645215feaf0 - 0x00005645215fff41 is .rodata
        0x00005645215fff44 - 0x0000564521600140 is .eh_frame_hdr
        0x0000564521600140 - 0x000056452160096c is .eh_frame
        0x0000564521600970 - 0x00005645216012f1 is .text
        0x00005645216012f4 - 0x000056452160130e is .init
        0x0000564521601310 - 0x0000564521601319 is .fini
        0x0000564521601320 - 0x00005645216014f0 is .plt
        0x0000564521602000 - 0x0000564521602010 is .data
        0x0000564521602010 - 0x0000564521602018 is .jcr
        0x0000564521602018 - 0x0000564521602018 is .tm_clone_table
        0x0000564521602018 - 0x0000564521602020 is .fini_array
        0x0000564521602020 - 0x0000564521602028 is .init_array
        0x0000564521602028 - 0x0000564521602fe8 is .data.rel.ro
        0x0000564521602fe8 - 0x0000564521603298 is .dynamic
        0x0000564521603298 - 0x00005645216034e0 is .got
        0x00005645216034e0 - 0x00005645216035d8 is .got.plt
        0x00005645216035e0 - 0x0000564521603ee4 is .bss
        0x00007f0bfa9e4190 - 0x00007f0bfa9e41b4 is .note.gnu.build-id in target:/pkg/lib/libmemdbg.so
        0x00007f0bfa9e41b8 - 0x00007f0bfa9e467c is .hash in target:/pkg/lib/libmemdbg.so
        0x00007f0bfa9e4680 - 0x00007f0bfa9e56a0 is .dynsym in target:/pkg/lib/libmemdbg.so
        0x00007f0bfa9e56a0 - 0x00007f0bfa9e60d1 is .dynstr in target:/pkg/lib/libmemdbg.so
        0x00007f0bfa9e60d2 - 0x00007f0bfa9e622a is .gnu.version in target:/pkg/lib/libmemdbg.so
        0x00007f0bfa9e6230 - 0x00007f0bfa9e62d0 is .gnu.version_r in target:/pkg/lib/libmemdbg.so
        0x00007f0bfa9e62d0 - 0x00007f0bfa9e6690 is .rela.dyn in target:/pkg/lib/libmemdbg.so
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
        0x00007f0bfa9e6690 - 0x00007f0bfa9e7158 is .rela.plt in target:/pkg/lib/libmemdbg.so

The output of info variables shows the type and the name of (global ?) available variables in the process's address space along with the name of the source file in which they are defined.
(gdb)info variables 
All defined variables:

File ../csu/init-first.c:
38:     int __libc_argc;
39:     char **__libc_argv;
34:     int __libc_multiple_libcs;

File ../elf/dl-sysdep.c:
61:     void *__GI___libc_stack_end;
56:     int __libc_enable_secure;
57:     int __libc_enable_secure_internal;
58:     int __libc_multiple_libcs;
62:     void *__libc_stack_end;
63:     void *_dl_random;
<output stripped........>
(gdb) 

How does gdb get the name of those source files ? They do not exist on the system gdb is running on.
Thanks.

They existed on the system where the code was compiled. Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678163

Ah ok, thus in any .so shared library is there an ELF specific section that "stores" infos regarding global variables and functions implemented in the library itself ?

Btw: why in some cases ELF executable/shared libraries contain .eh_frame and/or .debug_* sections but not .symtab section (i.e. it is stripped down)?
